# Another sum involving Benoulli numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, bernoulli-numbers

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770159/259363) that I am still working on, I needed to consider some sums involving Bernoulli numbers. After a lot of computations and simplifications, I ended up having to manipulate the following sum : $$\sum_{k=\ell+2}^{2\delta}\binom{k}{\ell+2}\binom{2\delta+2}{k+2}B_{2\delta-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2\delta-2-\ell}\binom{2\delta-k}{\ell+2}\binom{2\delta+2}{k}B_k,$$
where $0\leqslant\ell\leqslant2\delta-2$ and $\delta\geqslant2$. I tried several things, one of which being making use of [Weisstein formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition) : $$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m+1}{k}B_k=\delta_{m,0}.$$

I tried developing the binomial coefficients by making use of the factorial, using the various [identities involving them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients), or even trying summation by parts. Sadly, nothing of the sort worked. I'd also try using the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function) for the sequence $(B_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, but I have no clue about how I could proceed.

> **Is there a way to simplify the expression I gave above ?**

I'd need something slightly more suitable for algebraic reasoning, but I'm starting to doubt whether that's feasible... Does anyone have any clue/hint/idea on how to manipulate this expression ?

*Side note :* I plugged it into `Mathematica`, and it wasn't able to compute anything. But I doubt it has the sufficient knownledge (for instance, Weisstein or [Saalschütz](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662407110)).

---

*Update :* I have been advised to giving a try to [Volkenborn integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkenborn_integral), from which the Weisstein formula I gave above is a direct consequence. Therefore, manipulation of an expression such as $$\sum_{k=0}^{2\delta-2-\ell}\binom{2\delta-k}{\ell+2}\binom{2\delta+2}{k}X^k$$
may be useful. Unfortunately, I see no direct computation such as the Binomial expansion that can be used here, and `Mathematica` only rewrote the expression as : $$\sum_{k=0}^{2\delta-2-\ell}\binom{2\delta-k}{\ell+2}\binom{2\delta+2}{k}X^k=\binom{2\delta}{\ell+2}{_2F_1}(-2\delta-2,2-2\delta+\ell;-2\delta;X).$$

This may be a new starting point though, therefore I added it to this question.

Comment: When you say  you have to manipulate the identity involving sums of binomial and Berboulli numbers, you mean you want another expression "easier" for that sum? Of which type do you expect?

Comment: @xarles Yeah, an *easier* or *nicer* expression is what I'm looking for ! This sum is the degree $\ell$ coefficient of the polynomial I'm trying to prove irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$, but it seems like this raw expression is somewhat unusbable, as we don't know the numerators and denominators of each of these rational coefficients !