# Zeros of Faulhaber's formula

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials

I've noticed that $f_p(n) := \sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ has something interesting going with its zeros:
$$
\begin{align}
p = 0: &&0
\\
p = 1: &&-1, 0
\\
p = 2: && -1, -\frac12,0
\\
p = 3: &&-1,-1,0,0
\end{align}
$$
where in the latter multiplicity of zeros of $f_p$ is counted. For now I can say that $0$ is always a zero, all zeros are real and all are spread in $[-1, 0]$. Unfortunately, the latter condition is not satisfied already for $p = 4$, however the two zeros that fall out of this interval are still real and their sum is $-1$. Is there anything interesting known about zeros of $f_p$ in general?

Comment: If $p$ is odd larger than $1$, then $-1,-1,0,0$ are zeros. If $p$ is even, then $-1,-\frac 12,0$ are zeros. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials).

Comment: @mathlove thanks, saw that. Yet nothing close to some proper study of the behavior of zeros

Comment: What about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317391/573047)?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770159/259363

Comment: What are the zeroes of $p = 4$? I have a feeling that Bernoulli numbers are somehow involved.