# Where are the zeroes of complex exponential function?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, roots

There is none because we have $e^z \neq 0$ for every $z \in \mathbb C$.

But we have Taylor series that everywhere converges to $e^z$, it is $e^z = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} \frac {z^k}{k!}$.

If we truncate that series , say, at natural $m$, then we have Taylor polynomial $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac {z^k}{k!}$, which has, counted with maybe possible multiplicity, $m$ complex zeroes.

So as the degree of Taylor polynomial grows the number of zeroes increases, but in the limit they all dissapear, why?

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: Since the Taylor polynomial $T_n(z)$ tends to $e^z$ uniformly for $|z| < R$ for any fixed radius $R$, and $e^z$ has no zeroes, for large enough $n$ the zeroes of $T_n(z)$ must have $|z| > R$.  In other words - the zeroes must tend to infinity.  It would be interesting to see what the zeroes look like on the complex plane for large $n$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Do you think that they form some special polygons or something like that?

Comment: @anomaly Because there are reasons why the number of zeroes is not infinite.

Comment: @Right Yes, the zeroes of polynomial sequences often form interesting shapes.

Comment: At 11 PM, we put 10 balls numbered 1--10 into a bag, then remove the ball numbered 1.  At 11:30 PM, we put balls numbered 11--20 into a bag, then remove number 2.  At 11:45 PM, put 21--30 into the bag, and remove 3.  Repeat this procedure (at half the time to midnight, add ten balls, then remove the ball with the lowest number).  At midnight, how many balls are in the bag?  It turns out that the "right" answer is zero, since every ball is eventually removed before midnight.  At any finite step, there are more balls in the bag than in any previous step, but they are all gone by midnight.

Comment: You might think of something similar going on here.  Any finite approximation has a lot of zeros, but those zeroes are farther and farther out as the approximations get better.  The zeroes are being "pushed out" to infinity.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535720/5531) See also the questions under "Linked" on the sidebar there.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question.  A google search brings me to a [paper of Ian Zemke](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Ian.pdf), although this does not seem to have been peer-reviewed and I have not checked it myself.  He apparently proves that the zeroes of $T_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{k!}$ tend toward a specific curve, after normalization.  That is, if $p_n(z) = T_n(nz)$, then the zeroes of $p_n(z)$ are asymptotically close to the curve $$Γ = \{z : |ze^{1−z}
| = 1, |z| ≤ 1\}.$$  Thus the zeroes of the original $T_n(z)$ tend to infinity linearly with $n$.

A nice visualization from Zemke's paper:

[image]

Edit:  It seems this result is actually due to Gábor Szegő from 1924.  See Hans Lundmark's comment below.

Comment: This is a famous result by Szegő from 1924. See here for some more pictures: http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex/taylor/

Comment: @HansLundmark Ah, thanks!  I was not aware of this result.  Apparently my google-fu was not up to snuff.

Comment: Well, you still found a nice review paper! (I don't think Zemke claims that the proofs are original.) Here's another one, behind a paywall though: https://www.jstor.org/stable/30037629

Comment: That looks helpful too.  Your visualizations are very nice! There are also some interesting examples of zeroes of polynomial sequences from the great [Richard Stanley](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/zeros/).

Comment: More fun here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206890/the-egg-bizarre-behavior-of-the-roots-of-a-family-of-polynomials

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, that's one of my favorite math.se posts!