# Topology of the set of zeros of a family of polynomials

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry

My general question is very vague, so before let's look at the following example.
Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider a family of polynomials $p_a (z) = (az+1)^n - \dfrac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Here we view $a$ as a parameter of a family.

Let's fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough ($n=50$) and draw the sets of roots of $p_a(z)$ for some $a$'s.

For $a=1$ we have

[image]

For $a=\dfrac{10}9$:

[image]

For $a=\dfrac{12}9$:

[image]

For $a=\dfrac{15}9$:

[image]

For $a=2$:

[image]

First, when $a=1$ the roots lie near the circle and the $\Re =-\dfrac12$ line.
As $a$ increases the line transforms into another circle and finally the two circles merge.
For $a>2$ nothing new happens.
If one instead decreases $a$ then the second circle forms analogously.
The exact same pattern holds for any bigger $n$.

Now, in this particular example I do understand why any of this happens and my question is more general:

> Is there any theory that studies topology of zero sets for parametrized families of polynomials?

I'm not really sure what I precisely mean by topology in this case as the set of roots is discrete. Maybe some approximation by removing all the balls from $\mathbb{C}$ of fixed radius that do not intersect the set of roots. By varying the radius of such balls we will get different approximation.

Comment: These don't answer your question about the topology/things related to this "two circle" phenomenon, but you might be interested in links and discussion around the similarly-flavored [famous MathSE question about "the egg"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/206890/26369) and [the MathOverflow question about roots of random polynomials often clustering around the unit circle](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182412/28209).

Comment: There is a beautiful results due to Jentzsch which asserts that for any power series, every point of the circle of convergence is a limit point of of zeros of partial sums. This nicely breaks up from your pictures, the case $a=1$ being the simplest. Jentzsch theorem can be find in  Titchmarsch "Theory of functions".

Comment: @MarkS. I have not found the question from your first link when I did my research. Very interesting, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Salcio Thanks!